# How to update metrics in aws cloud watch using boto3 through python code?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, boto3

I want to make application that send live values to AWS cloud watch like sensor data. Is there any way to send live data to cloud watch ?I made a python code that publish custom metric to AWS cloud successfully .How can i change this value Frequently?

Comment: How did it go. Is it still unclear why you can't update metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .How can i change this value Frequently?

You can't change existing metric values as they are **immutable**. You can only add new ones based on the increasing values of your timestamps.